# Затемнение рабочего стола

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Всем привет, как в PyQt5 реализовать затемнение как на скрине?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background: black")
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.showFullScreen()

    ok = QMessageBox.question(None, 'Question', 'Question?')
    if ok == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print('User select Ok')
    else:
        print('User select No')

    # Убираем затемнение
    mw.close()

    app.exec()
```

---

**UPD.** Версия 2.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt


class EgoDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        # Задний фон не будет нарисован, это нужно чтобы через paintEvent его рисовать
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    @staticmethod
    def exec(title: str, text: str) -> bool:
        mw = EgoDialog()
        mw.showFullScreen()

        ok = QMessageBox.question(mw, title, text)
        mw.close()

        return ok == QMessageBox.Yes

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 127))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    ok = EgoDialog.exec('Question', 'Question?')
    if ok:
        print('User select Ok')
    else:
        print('User select No')

    # app.exec()
```

Comment: На маке и то и то выглядит некорректно, а вторая версия так глюканула, что пришлось `pkill Python`(даже пайчарм не закрывался)

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще не плохой пример, но если свернуть окно и развернуть необходимо на иконку на панели нажать два раза.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class EgoDialog(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.resize(500, 500)
    self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

class back(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.setStyleSheet("background: black")
    self.setWindowOpacity(0.7)
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication([])
win = EgoDialog()
win.show()
back = back()
back.showFullScreen()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `Qt::Tool windows cannot be made Qt::WindowFullScreen`

Comment: Вместо Qt.Tool можно попробовать Qt.SplashScreen

Comment: Получается очень интересный эффект, только в фулскрине он не прозрачный.Хотя окно видно.Но оно не в фокусе.